# Rails_admin returns 500 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, production, rails-admin

I'm using rails 5.1, ruby 2.3.3, rails_admin '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.2'

Whiles everything is working as supposed in development environment, when I push my code to Heroku and go to `/admin` I get:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Heroku Logs:

```
2019-03-14T14:37:24.174624+00:00 app[web.1]: [26495061-dae1-4201-9940-b2fd9b2bbec3] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rails_admin-1.4.2/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/application.html.haml:9:in `_vendor_bundle_ruby_______gems_rails_admin_______app_views_layouts_rails_admin_application_html_haml___4595881635924699580_46923427520660'
2019-03-14T14:37:24.174626+00:00 app[web.1]: [26495061-dae1-4201-9940-b2fd9b2bbec3] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.1.6.2/lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `block in render'
2019-03-14T14:37:24.174628+00:00 app[web.1]: [26495061-dae1-4201-9940-b2fd9b2bbec3] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
2019-03-14T14:37:24.174630+00:00 app[web.1]: [26495061-dae1-4201-9940-b2
2019-03-14T14:37:24.175890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin" host=geenyland.herokuapp.com request_id=26495061-dae1-4201-9940-b2fd9b2bbec3 fwd="41.66.209.190" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=562ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2019-03-14T14:37:24.731676+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=geenyland.herokuapp.com request_id=bc9f2e56-9906-4571-9fb8-de437250f015 fwd="41.66.209.190" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

Comment: the code above is trimmed

Comment: The piece of the log you posted doesn’t include the actual error message.

Comment: You have a `status=500`, which means something broke. Run `heroku logs --tail` and check what went wrong.

Comment: @RickS i run heroku logs --tail =>  and i got this =>

Comment: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/"    request_id=a64c4c6e-910b-4cf0-ab2d-ea87de829e5c fwd="197.251.240.135" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=175ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact issue and looking through my logs didn't give me much help. However, I'm really new to rails and am learning to read logs to troubleshoot things. What did help was the link Jose posted for the [official guide from Heroku for a rails project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#deploy-your-application-to-heroku.). A simple `heroku run rake db:migrate` fixed my problem.